# Linking CSS file to a HTML document

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my CSS.

For example I have this code in my CSS file

```
.readmore {
    font-style: italic;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #509743;
    padding-left: 15px;
    background: url(../images/more.png) no-repeat 0 50%;
}
.readmore:hover{
    color: #c8c8c8;

}
```

When I call it from the HTML file it doesn't work, but when I make a copy of the CSS code in HTML file it's working fine.

This is the HTML code

```
  <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-4" style="position:relative; top:20px; margin-left:10px;">
    <div class="thumbnail">

      <div class="caption">

      <h4>A propos de  <strong><span style="color:#509743;">L'agence</span></strong></h4>   


                <img src="images/logo_agence.gif"/><br><br>
           <p><a href="#" class="readmore">...</a></p><br><br>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

When I put this code it's fine, but I don't like it's not professional and it looks bad.

```
             <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-4" style="position:relative; top:20px; margin-left:10px;">
    <div class="thumbnail">

      <div class="caption">

      <h4>A propos de  <strong><span style="color:#509743;">L'agence</span></strong></h4>   


                <img src="images/logo_agence.gif"/><br><br>
           <p><a href="#" style="
    font-style: italic;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #509743;
    padding-left: 15px;
    background: url(images/more.png) no-repeat 0 50%;

hover{
    color: #c8c8c8;

}">...</a></p><br><br>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Hover doesn't work.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Can you show how you link your CSS file in the HTML?

Comment: Yes of course <link rel="stylesheet" type ="text/css" href="cssbootstrap/Style1.css">

Comment: is this in `HEAD` tag of your `HTML`?

Comment: Is the path to the file correct according to your file structure? 
Maybe try '/cssbootstrap/Style1.css'

Comment: @user3215993, can you show in your question the part of the HTML you put your `<link ....>` please? Are you sure the path is correct and your CSS file starts with a capital S?

Answer (score 2):

How are you linking the CSS from your HTML? If you're using a link element, it should be in the document's `<head>` and take the following form:

```
<link href="path/to/your/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

You need all three attributes. If it doesn't work, the first thing is to make sure the path is correct. You can use the network tab in your browser's developer tools to see if the CSS file is being found (if the path is incorrect it will probably show up as a 404 error).

You may also need to make sure the server is sending the file down with the correct MIME type. It should be `text/css`.

By the way, `:hover` doesn't work because you can't put pseudo-selectors into inline styles.

Comment: I forget one important thing my css file have not only readmore for example 


    p{ font-size: 12px; color: #555555; line-height: 18px; } 


this code of paragraphe work fine and other things work also fine so the probleme of linking file is fine no probleme with it i don't know where is the probleme

Comment: other things when i change the file Style1.css from cssbootstrap to other place the size of my page change and i understand that boostrap file and Style.css work together i don't understand any thing because they don't have any relation between

Comment: @user3215993 Do you mean you more than one CSS file linked to the HTML document? They will both have an effect on the document, and [which rules take precedence depends on their specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/). So it may be that `.readmore` is being overridden by another, more specific rule. To figure that out, we'd need to see more of the code.

Comment: to avoid this probleme i have deleted all file that don't have relation with bootstrap file  and after that of course i have another form of my page now i will create another subject of this probleme and thank you very mush